# Inserting Blob Content into another Blob (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($get_orange = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_image)){
$orange = $get_orange['image'];
$insert_test = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `image_test` (`id`,`image`) VALUES ('','".$orange."'");
}
```

How would I do this? The variable **orange** is the blob content, and I am trying to insert this blob content into another blob of a different table. If this is possible, how would I do this? I am in need of this for many features of my website.

Comment: remove the concatenation, just put the $orange in single quotes: `VALUES ('', '$orange')`. And I think in your case your are not enclosing the query `VALUES ('','".$orange."'")` => `VALUES ('','".$orange."');")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single query that combines selecting from one table with inserting into another:

```
INSERT INTO `image_test` (`id`, `image`) SELECT '', `image` FROM `images`;
```

You didn't show your original SELECT query, so I'm guessing a bit. The above query will insert **all** rows from images into image_test. You can add WHERE conditions as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this absolutely works. Is there any way I can give you a reward or something? :)

Comment: Just mark the answer as accepted - that'll reward both of us with a reputation increase, and lets other people that view this question know that the answer worked.

Comment: Done. Except, do you know how I would make a UPDATE query using a sub-select? I have never done this before, but it may be very useful to me later on with my website.

Comment: Please post that as a new question.